# Function to change background of a toggle button when pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a function to change the background image of a toggle button when it is pressed but it is not working out for me.

I currently have this function:

```
public Image Background1;
public Image Background2;
public Toggle theToggle;

public void ChangeBackground()
        {
        if (theToggle.isOn) {
            theToggle.image () = Background1;
        }
        else
        {
            theToggle.image() = Background2;
            }
        }
```

My problem is that in the scene view I don't receive the slot option to add an image  to Background1 and Background2 like it happens on other scripts. Also the image parameterer is not recognized by the editor despite the fact it is on the scripting reference and that I have added the UI lybrary using:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Also, I tried to put the ChangeBackground() function inside the Update() function like this and I receive a parse error:

```
public Image Background1;
public Image Background2;
public Toggle theToggle;

void Update () 
    {
        public void ChangeBackground()
        {
        if (theToggle.isOn) {
            theToggle.image () = Background1;
        }
        else
        {
            theToggle.image() = Background2;
            }
        }
    }
```

This parse error is very strange because this is the way i did in other scripts. Can you help me?

Comment: you simply have " () " which should not be there.  it's just `.image=`

Comment: DO NOT do the "+=" thing shown below; that is not your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one, you have a compiler error because you're attempting to call the function "image" and assign it a value at the same time. My guess is you wanted to set the image attribute to some Sprite type variable "Background1"

So you'd change that like this:

```
public void ChangeBackground()
{
        if (theToggle.isOn) {
            theToggle.image = Background1;
        }
        else
        {
            theToggle.image = Background2;
            }
        }        
}
```

Now, when there is a compiler error, the inspector will not update with new fields from a script. So if you have declared variables somewhere in your script (usually after the class declaration) like so:

```
public Image background1;
public Image background2;
```

They will appear in the inspector, waiting to be set, as long as you have no compiler errors and they are public

Also, you can't put a function declaration, nor would you want to, in C# and most programming languages.

You **MUST** drag the `ChangeBackground` function ON TO YOUR TOGGLE.  Drag it to here...

[image]

---

Note! the following is highly advanced information, not immediately relevant to Grow's question as such.

An easy way to apply the ChangeBackground function whenever the toggle is toggled, you could simply do it in script by including these two functions:

```
void OnEnable()
{
    theToggle.onValueChanged += ChangeBackground
}

void OnDisable()
{
    theToggle.onValueChanged -= ChangeBackground
}
```

Comment: I have just added the variables declaration to the answer, I will look into your response now, thanks!

Comment: Why can't I put this function inside Update()?

Comment: I edited the answer a few times; see new bottom for calling the function whenever the toggle changes.

Comment: You can't "put" the function in Update because you're trying to tell the compiler something it doesn't understand. You can call the function in Update like so: void Update() { ChangeBackground(); },

but again, you wouldn't want to because it would unnecessarily perform a check and set the background to itself every tick, whereas you could just subscribe the function to an event, like I did in the OnEnable function, which will only call it when you change the value of the toggle.

Comment: hi @BilalItani .. the second part of your answer is totally unnecessary in unity3D .. you just "drag" that connection to the toggle, in the Editor.

Comment: hi @BilalItani I edited in an explanation and an image.  of course what you said is correct, but you are far too advanced, Bilal !  :)  the OP simply needs to know how to drag in the Editor

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm aware you can drag, I planned to include an image, but was short on time. Thanks for adding one!

As a side note, however, it's generally better to refer through script as dragging in the inspector can get a bit disorganized, and it also requires that the gameobjects you reference are already in the scene. That means that if you want to add the functionality from a gameobject you newly created, you would have to do it through script.

In my opinion, it's good to expose best practices early on, so people don't have too much difficulty fixing older code in case they need to.

Comment: hi @BilalItani !  yes, it's good that even absolute beginners are aware of the dynamic technique.