# Changing background of toggle button when pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I want to change the background of a toggle button when it is pressed. I already created the button using the new UI system and created a script with the function to change the background.

In the scene view, I can see that the target graphic of the toggle button is changing as I desire, but the background of the toggle still don't change.

I am attaching what I see on the inspector, I hope you can tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You have asked this question more than 3 times in 3 days. What color are you trying to change it to? Change the toggle button from white to black? Or change the image of the button? Why not  provide the code you have to toggles the backgound in your question.

Comment: But I have been making progress, I did not pasted the code because it is working. In the image I sent you can see that the target graphic is changing when the toggle changes state.

Comment: I don't want to change color of background, I want to change the image of the background. Please see the Target Graphic in the inspector

Comment: heh .. are you trying to change the thing labelled **SOURCE IMAGE** on the **RIGHT MOST PANEL IN YOUR IMAGE**

Comment: I get it. You want the background image changed and that is happening in editor view.  For the last picture you put up, what's is that for? I am confused as Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so look at the previous explanation of your same question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35921218/294884

```
public void ChangeBackground()
{
        if (theToggle.isOn) {   WRONG
            theToggle.image = Background1;}  WRONG
        else
        {  theToggle.image = Background2; }  WRONG
        }        
}
```

notice it changes something called "the toggle".

***WRONG!***

## FIRST, MAKE A VARIABLE CALLED "iWantToChangeTHIS"...

```
public Image iWantToChangeTHIS;
public Sprite oneSprite;
public Sprite twoSprite;

public Toggle theToggle;

public void ChangeBackground()
  {
   if (theToggle.isOn)
     iWantToChangeTHIS.sprite = oneSprite;
   else
     iWantToChangeTHIS.sprite = twoSprite;
  }        
}
```

## Next, drag WHAT YOU ACTUALLY WANT TO CHANGE to the variable "iWantToChangeTHIS"

As usual, drag the toggle to "theToggle" and drag the two sprites (from your Project panel) to the Sprite items.

You're done.

Comment: This looks like what he is looking for but his question a bit confusing.

Comment: @JoeBlow it seems I cannot call the image on iWantToChangeTHIS, it says there is no definition for UnityEngine.UI.image

Comment: I guess I could call the image parameter before because it was being called on a Toggle, and now I am calling it on an Image

Comment: I guess I don't need to call it now, because I am already dealing with an image

Answer (score 0):

*Just wanted to share the script I made for our projects;*

*You can use this to change a toggle object's target image (usually background)
**AND/OR**, to toggle the visibility of a second checkmark-like graphic.*

- Create a new script,
- Name it 'ToggleImageSwap' (or change the class in the code according to your script name),
- Paste this code in the script,
- Attach it to your toggle.
- Select what you want.

  - If you want a to keep the background intact, you can basically duplicate the CheckMark child object of your toggle and change its sprite to the sprite that you want to show when the toggle is unchecked.

*I tried to explain a bit more in variable comments.*

**Here is the code;**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Toggle))]
public class ToggleImageSwap : MonoBehaviour
{
    //First, we get the target Toggle Component. 
    //Even if you don't select the target Toggle component here, the script get the one one the same object.
    [SerializeField] private Toggle targetToggle;

    //This means that we want to actually "Swap" the target image which is set in Toggle component. 
    //By default, it is the "Background".
    //You may want to use this while "Checkmark" image set to "none" for traditional effect.
    [SerializeField] private bool swapTogglesTargetGraphic = true;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite swapSprite;

    //This means that we want to "Enable" a different image instead of "Checkmark" image when the toggle is unchecked.
    //You need to create a new image to use this, you can just duplicate Checkmark image and change it.
    [SerializeField] private bool enableUncheckedGraphic = false;
    [SerializeField] private Graphic uncheckedGraphic;


    void Start () {
        if (targetToggle == null)
            targetToggle = GetComponent<Toggle>();
        targetToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnTargetToggleValueChanged);
        targetToggle.toggleTransition = Toggle.ToggleTransition.None;
        if (uncheckedGraphic != null)
            uncheckedGraphic.CrossFadeAlpha(targetToggle.isOn ? 0f : 1f, 0f, true);
    }

    void OnTargetToggleValueChanged(bool toggleValue) {
        if (swapTogglesTargetGraphic)
        {
            Image targetImage = targetToggle.targetGraphic as Image;
            if (targetImage != null) {
                if (toggleValue) 
                    targetImage.overrideSprite = swapSprite;
                else 
                    targetImage.overrideSprite = null;
            }
        }
        if (enableUncheckedGraphic)
        {
            uncheckedGraphic.CrossFadeAlpha(toggleValue ? 0f : 1f, 0f, true);
        }
    }
}
```